# Left and Right Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I require left and right drawers in my application.

My layout looks like:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >     

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detail_fragment"
        android:name="my detail fragment class name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:name="My LeftDrawerFragment class name"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:name="My RightDrawerFragment class name"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

So through my left drawer and right drawer fragments I am loading the drawers.
Content is loading but I am not able to position the right drawer icon. Only one drawer icon is coming and that too in the left. How can I achieve both left and right drawers? Can anyone figure out my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to use Left and right navigation drawer use this library. its very easy to setup and easy understand and its very stable. [This Link](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) as i have implemented it in my lots of projects.
you can set left and right drawer by this:

```
SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
```

For left:

```
 menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
```

For right:

```
 menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
```

Comment: Hey Kishan, Thanks for your reply..This is actually an existing project and completely done in this manner. Not in a state to change the library.